# achartengine - inclined labels position

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using **achartengine** to show a temperature graph. on X axis I put dates, to fit them I call setXLabelsAngle(45); this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the labels are **placed too high** and go over the x-Axis. How could I fix this? I'm already using setMargins(), but labels don't move, only legend does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help:

```
renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
```

Comment: I've tried `Align.LEFT` and `Align.CENTER` with no success. I'll try LEFT and report. Thank you

Comment: yes, it works, thank you. I suggest to document this inside setXLabelsAngle() javadoc